# Check if an audio snippet is present somewhere in an audio track

Tags: python-3.x, bash, audio, command-line

Let's say I have an `mp3` file which contains the intro of the show Friends (+-60sec long), which we'll call audio track `audio1`.

I also have a complete episode of Friends (+-25min long), which we'll call audio track `audio2`.

My goal is to match `audio2` against `audio1` and receive the beginning and ending time of the match. That means that, as an example, the beginning time would be around 1m30s and the ending around 2m15s.

If found this [Audacity forum post](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?t=82354) and this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/clee704/audiodiff), but I haven't been able to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supposed to catch the same jingles or speech too?

Comment: Comparing sounds (sound matching) is difficult, unless the samples are 100% identical, which is unlikely in your case (different formats, maybe different sampling rates, compression ratios or even completely different recording sessions...). This is an active research topic. If you are a PhD student and you are doing research on this, SO is not the right place. Journals and conferences on audio processing are much better places. Else, I doubt you'll find a ready-to-use tool. Organize a binge watching night with lot of friends?